# what is sudo command used for

Tags: sudo

Can anybody explain or point the use of sudo command, perhaps the os give su command. Does it not solve the problem of login as superuser.

Let me rephrase it 
1) what is the advantages of sudo over su ?
2) what are notable features of sudo ?

Comment: @Zypher, Wow, couldn't someone have just edited this.  Too bad they don't allow suggested edits for closed questions.  It's obviously a real question, just a very basic one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sudo command is used to give a particular command root rights for a single instance.

If your user belongs to the sudo group, you can type: "sudo command"
Then enter your password and it will be executed as root.

This is very common on Mac OSX, as typically passwords for the root account are not the same as your admin account. Therefor, if you need a root shell, you could always "sudo bash" to accomplish this.